# Problem with importing configurable products, associated products not shows up

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, importexport

I have the problem, that the "Associated Products" not shows up under the configurabel product.

We are using Magento 1.9.1, I did the import over Import, then choose the file.

Here is the file, maybe we forgot to add something:

```
sku,store,attribute_set,config_attributes,type,category_id,root_category,product_websites,apparel_size,brand_name,color,configurable_products,cost,country_of_manufacture,created_at,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,description,disable_amazonpayments,featured,gallery,gift_message_available,has_options,image,image_label,manufacturer,media_gallery,meta_description,meta_keyword,meta_title,minimal_price,msrp,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp_enabled,name,news_from_date,news_to_date,options_container,page_layout,price,required_options,short_description,size,small_image,small_image_label,special_from_date,special_price,special_to_date,status,tax_class_id,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,updated_at,url_key,url_path,visibility,weight,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
VX-313011,,Apparel-attribute-set,color,configurable,13/124,Default Category,base,One size,Victorinox,,"VX-313011-01-OS,VX-313011-03-OS,VX-313011-01-OS",,,4/8/2015 23:09,,,,,"With organization for any agenda, this slimline case has protective compartments for both a laptop and an iPad or Kindle
",No,No,,,1,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,Victorinox WT Shopping Tote,,,Product Info Column,,169.99,1,"Interior organization includes a 15.6” (40 cm) laptop compartment, 10” / 25 cm portable electronic device pocket and two mesh peripherals pockets",,,,,,,1,0,,,8/4/2015 19:35,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor.html,1,,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,/1/1/119190.jpg,,1,0,,,,
VX-313011-01-OS,,Apparel-attribute-set,color,simple,13/124,,base,,Victorinox,Black,,,,4/8/2015 23:09,,,,,"With organization for any agenda, this slimline case has protective compartments for both a laptop and an iPad or Kindle
",No,No,,,0,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,"Victorinox WT Shopping Tote, black",,,Product Info Column,,169.99,0,"Interior organization includes a 15.6” (40 cm) laptop compartment, 10” / 25 cm portable electronic device pocket and two mesh peripherals pockets",,,,,,,1,0,,,8/4/2015 19:35,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor-black,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor-black.html,1,2,10,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
VX-313011-03-OS,,Apparel-attribute-set,color,simple,13/124,,base,,Victorinox,Grey,,,,4/8/2015 23:09,,,,,"With organization for any agenda, this slimline case has protective compartments for both a laptop and an iPad or Kindle
",No,No,,,0,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,"Victorinox WT Shopping Tote, grey",,,Product Info Column,,169.99,0,"Interior organization includes a 15.6” (40 cm) laptop compartment, 10” / 25 cm portable electronic device pocket and two mesh peripherals pockets",,,,,,,1,0,,,8/4/2015 19:35,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor-olive,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor-olive.html,1,2,10,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
VX-313011-06-OS,,Apparel-attribute-set,color,simple,13/124,,base,,Victorinox,Olive,,,,4/8/2015 23:09,,,,,"With organization for any agenda, this slimline case has protective compartments for both a laptop and an iPad or Kindle
",No,No,,,0,,,,,,,,,,Use config,Use config,"Victorinox WT Shopping Tote, olive",,,Product Info Column,,169.99,0,"Interior organization includes a 15.6” (40 cm) laptop compartment, 10” / 25 cm portable electronic device pocket and two mesh peripherals pockets",,,,,,,1,0,,,8/4/2015 19:35,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor-olive,victorinox-303337-werks-professional-advisor-olive.html,1,2,10,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```